# Accidentally skipped encryption dialog after installation. How to resume?

Tags: 10.10, installation, ecryptfs

During Ubuntu installation I chose to encrypt my home folder. Accidently after installation I skipped the dialog in ubuntu where I was asked to setup encryption (choose key and so on ...)

How can I resume and complete the encryption process?

Update: The Encryption dialog box after installation just offers to show your passphrase for note it. Enryption process after installation is fully completed with a random generated passphrase during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links were helpful

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ecryptfs/Nutzung

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ecryptfs/Datenrettung

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/359997

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/359997/comments/2

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/359997/comments/3

This command to read out your passphrase which was created although i skipped the mentioned dialog

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase $HOME/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

These commands to check if there are already the ecrypt directories

```
mount | grep ecryptfs

ls -aFl | grep ecryptfs
```

Update: Also check this [Question with Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17216/how-can-i-determine-if-just-the-private-folder-is-encrypted-or-the-whole-home-di) for information on how to determine which folders are encypted.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a regular (non encrypted) home dir, and you want to convert it to an encrypted home, you must follow this procedure: 
http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/06/migrating-to-encrypted-home-directory.html