# How can I determine if just the .private folder is encrypted or the whole home directory?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

How can i determine if just the .private folder is encrypted or the whole home directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the terminal type:

```
cat /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt
```

If the file exists and contains your home directory path, your home directory is encrypted.

Another way to check is looking at your home dir mount point:

From the terminal type:

```
df $HOME
```

An encrypted home will be mounted at  the ".Private" filesystem, otherwise it will be mounted at some regular partition device (/dev/*) .

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/home/username/.Private
                     315482376 101351268 198105472  34% /home/username
```

Regular device mount (no encryption):

```
df /home/schroot
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7            315482376 101351332 198105408  34% /home
```

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but let's assume /home was encrypted before a system reinstallation. During installation, /home partition wasn't formatted or touched in any way. Would it still be encrypted? The .Private and .encryptfs folders would still be there, won't they? But I assume that you couldn't access this /home partition if it wasn't properly encrypted?

Answer (score 7):

This is a great question!  It actually comes up a lot, from a programmatic perspective.  Programs, processes, and applications like the Ubuntu installer, lightdm, and gdm actually need to know if $HOME is encrypted, or Private, and if they're set up properly.

I've recently written a utility, [ecryptfs-verify-private](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/utils/ecryptfs-verify), that was be released in the eCryptfs release version 96.

Comment: Great script, thank you! I got two errors: (1) invalid owner of mount point and (2) configuration invalid. What does that mean?