# How (if at all) can I recover lost gnome settings after unclean shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, gconf

I had a power outage the other day and when I started Ubuntu afterwards it told me that it found some errors on disk, fixed them and restarted. Then I finally got to login and:

- I have all my regular files in my home directory
- I am missing all my gnome settings (from wifi passkeys that were saved to desktop background to chrome profile)
- My firefox retained all the settings
- [can provide more symptoms, if that would help]

My home directory used to be encrypted, and following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17216/how-can-i-determine-if-just-the-private-folder-is-encrypted-or-the-whole-home-d), I see it still is. I have tried restarting / logging in-out and once saw my wallpaper appear (and then the session crashed...). So I believe that the settings are still "out-there". So, what can I check / how can I understand what exactly is my situation and whether (and how) I can recover all my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I [found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix) that the "errors on disk" part meant that fsck was run and the fact that it fixed "something" essentially meant that some data on disk became corrupt.

I checked lost+found folder - and indeed, it contained some of the data I was missing. Most of it, however, is gone forever.