# How to check if your home folder and swap partition are encrypted using terminal?

Tags: encryption

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a few days ago but strangely I seem to have skipped the part about choosing to encrypt home folder. Now if it is encrypted I do not know what is the encryption key. How do I check if it is really encrypted? (and also the swap partition).

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/17216/how-can-i-determine-if-just-the-private-folder-is-encrypted-or-the-whole-home-d

Comment: You probably could have recovered the passphrase using `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` or `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /path/to/wrapped-passphrase` (if the automatically created "wrapped-passphrase" file had not been deleted), see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase.1.html.

NB: When `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` asks for your passphrase, enter the user's password.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Open terminal and type `ls -A /home`. There should be a `.ecryptfs` folder, if you have encryption of your home folder.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. I do have .ecryptfs folder. So my home folder is encrypted.

Comment: Also there is a related question regarding swap partition, http://askubuntu.com/questions/53242/check-if-partition-is-encrypted
My swap is encrypted as well.

Comment: ...so Eve's `mkdir ~/.ecryptfs` (or `tar xf files-expected-on-an-encrypted-home.tgz`) would make Alice believe her home is safely encrypted, while it actually *isn't*?

Comment: @Iserni: Indeed! I think one should rather look through `mount` then. I haven't thought about that before.

Comment: You do not want to list contents of the current directory, so please exclude the ` .` from the command.

Comment: @jarno: I think the formatting was just wrong and that it should be the period in the sentence. I have fixed that.

Comment: to check your home you could also do `mount | grep /home` and you'll get something like `/home/.ecryptfs/your-username/.Private on /home/your-username type ecryptfs ...`

Answer (score 18):

This is how to check if swap partition is encrypted:

```
sudo blkid | grep swap
```

and should check for an output similar to

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="95f3d64d-6c46-411f-92f7-867e92991fd0" TYPE="swap"
```

If instead of `cryptswap1` there is something like a usual drive (e.g. `/dev/sda4`) then swap area is not encrypted.

Comment: What if I see both `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` and a usual drive in the output?