# Why the cryptographic key was not provided at ubuntu 12.04 first run?

Tags: encryption

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a few days ago and strangely I missed the part where we choose to encrypt home folder.

However I already ran the commands on this question ([How to check if your home folder and swap partition are encrypted using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146511/how-to-check-if-your-home-folder-and-swap-partition-are-encrypted-using-terminal)) to check if home folder and swap partition are encrypted and they are.

So why is that Ubuntu did not provide me the cryptographic key the same way it happened when I installed Ubuntu 11.04???

Comment: Did you reinstall over an existing installation?

Comment: Thanks @ObsessiveFOSS for reminding me, some of this problems were about Lubuntu, which meanwhile I uninstalled in order to use default Ubuntu, and I forgot about some of the previous questions. I am now marking best answers to close the questions :)

Comment: No @Gilles I didn't, I installed from live USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still don't know why the passphrase for home folder encryption was not provided at first run, anyway, with a simple command in terminal, it is possible to get this passphrase.

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

This is useful if it is ever needed to make a manual recovery of the data present in encrypted home folder, as described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering_Your_Data_Manually